# equivalent of LocationManager .onLocationChanged in objective c

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cllocationmanager

I am a newbie with objective c style development. I have an android app which I am trying to convert into an iPhone app.

In the android app I have a `LocationManager`, `LocationListener` created, which `onLocationChanged()` behaves the usual way to give me the updated location, as and when it changes.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
              // some logic here 
         }

   locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, minTimeInterval, 0,
            locationListener);
```

I have used the `CLLocationManager` to generate location information in the ios app

```
 self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
if ( [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] ) {
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 100;
    [self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

how do I ensure that as and when the location changes this would be called and I would get the new location information. Of course at this point in time I am using the ios simulator and not the iphone hardware, but technically I would want this to work on the iphone too.

any suggestions ?

Comment: - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
     fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLLocationManager) and the [CLLocationManagerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/CLLocationManagerDelegate) protocol. The class which implements CLLocationManagerDelegate gets the new location via method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```